# How to make the UIView as Like Ticket in UITablevViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, swift5

### TicketViewTableViewCell.swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var ticketView: TestView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
    ticketView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    ticketView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    ticketView.circleRadius = 10
    
    ticketView.circleY = ticketView.frame.height * 0.6
}


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
   }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVaFz.png)

I want to get the UIView like the above image in TableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom view as a background view:

```
@IBDesignable class TicketBackground: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 4
    @IBInspectable var indentRadius : CGFloat = 10
    @IBInspectable var color : UIColor = UIColor.lightGray

    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawBackground()
    }
    
    private func drawBackground()
    {
        
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        let width = self.frame.width
        let height = self.frame.height
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width-cornerRadius, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width-cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height/2-indentRadius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width, y: height/2), radius: indentRadius, startAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height-cornerRadius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width-cornerRadius, y: height-cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height-cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height/2+indentRadius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height/2), radius: indentRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi/2, endAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: 3*CGFloat.pi/2, clockwise: true)
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = self.color.cgColor
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
}
```